# How to exclude elements from select (drop down)

Tags: java, selenium, automation

```
List<WebElement> selectedOpts = driver.findElements(
     By.cssSelector("select.form-control > option:checked"));

for(WebElement temp : selectedOpts ) {
  System.out.println(temp.getText());
}
```

I have executed the code and got the below result

```
**Result**
2tec2 Sales Network
Active
Selenium,Chennai,345/45,London Street-2
```

Now i want to exclude Selenium,Chennai,345/45,London Street-2 from my selection.

```
HTML
**html code**

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-4 col-sm-4" for="type- 
select">Category<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
        <select defaultattr="4" class="form-control input-style mandatory" 
data-val="true" data-val-number="The field CategoryID must be a number." 
id="CategoryID" name="CategoryID"><option value="">--Select--</option>
<option value="1">Architectural Firm</option>
<option selected="selected" value="2">2tec2 Sales Network</option>
<option value="3">Cleaning Company</option>
</select>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-4 col-sm-4" for="type-select">Company 
Status</label>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
        <select class="form-control input-style" id="ddlCompanyStatus">
                <option selected="selected" value="1">Active</option>
                <option value="0">Non Active</option>
        </select>
    </div>
<div class="form-group"> 
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-4 col-sm-4" for="type-select">Company</label>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
            <select class="form-control input-style CallChange" id="ddlCompany" defaultattr="1568">
                        <option value="1107">2Tec2 Flooring,Chennai,Anna Salai,Raheja Towers</option>
                        <option selected="" value="1568">Selenium,Chennai,345/45,London Street-2</option>
                        <option value="1494">Test again,Wervik,Kasteelstraat 113</option>
```

There are 3 dropdown lists options and I want to select first two selected options text in the dropdown. By executing the above code all the 3 are getting selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String locator = "select#CategoryID > option:checked, " + 
                 "select#ddlCompanyStatus> option:checked"

List<WebElement> selectedOpts = driver.findElements(
     By.cssSelector(locator));

for(WebElement temp : selectedOpts ) {
  System.out.println(temp.getText());
}
```